# handwrite drawing is a bit late it's like echo for my finger ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I draw on an image so i can store it as `NSData` to load it and reuse it , so i use the following code to do so , but when i write , the writing is following my finger moves not instant , i need it to be done instantly not like watching a reply to my finger writing 
the code :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

     if(penImg.userInteractionEnabled){
        touchh = [touches anyObject];
        lastpoint = [touchh locationInView:penImg];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(penImg.frame.size);
        [penImg.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, penImg.frame.size.width, penImg.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        lastpoint.y -= 20;
        if (astyca){
            CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 25.0);
        }
        else {

            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), redC, greenC, blueC, 1.0);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
        }
        CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    }
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (penImg.userInteractionEnabled){

        touchh = [touches anyObject];
        currentPnt = [touchh locationInView:penImg];
        countTouches = [event allTouches];
        if (countTouches.count == 2)
            return;
        currentPnt.y -= 20;


        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastpoint.x, lastpoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPnt.x, currentPnt.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        penImg.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        lastpoint = currentPnt;
    }
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (penImg.userInteractionEnabled){
        //UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        NSSet *countTouchess = [event allTouches];
        if (countTouchess.count == 2)
            return;
        if (astyca)
            CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
        else CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), redC, greenC, blueC, 1.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastpoint.x, lastpoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastpoint.x, lastpoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        penImg.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

how to make it draw instantly just below my finger not following my finger , thanks 
and if you suggest another method please mention how to save and load it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not draw outside `-drawRect:`. Collect the points in your event methods (`-touches…`), trigger a redraw (`-setNeedsDisplay`) and then draw the collected points in `-drawRect:`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/ (The View Drawing Cycle)

Comment: will i then be able to draw on the penImg ? as it's an imageView

Comment: You have to draw the entire content of your view in `-drawRect:` occupying the passed rect. (The easiest way to do this is simply to draw the entire view, that means, not restricted to the passed rect.)

Comment: how to draw the points on a uiImageView , i still don't know the answer of my question :(

Comment: You do not have to change your drawing code, but simply to move it to `-drawRect:`.

Comment: oh i got it , i will test if that will make a difference ^___^

Comment: It makes a difference as documented. ;-)

Comment: but i need that to happen in a specific viewController , and these functions requires a UIView class X___X

Comment: I don't understand that!? If you want a custom drawing, you need a custom `UIView` subclass.

Comment: these functions (setNeedsDisplay and drawRect) can be implemented only in a UIView class , and i wanted to implement that in a UIViewController Class